# Apple News Preview -- can't load articles

Tags: macos-mojave, apple-news

I am attempting to use News Preview to check out my apple news articles, but I keep getting the error "This document couldn't be opened. For details, see the error console...". The error console seems to be completely blank.

I have tried this with article json directly from my server and also json downloaded from iCloud's news publisher. The articles in question display fine on my test news channels in the Apple News app.

Has anyone had this issue before?

Edit: I have the latest version of XCode installed. The same result occurs when I try to load articles downloaded from [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/apple_news/apple_news_format_tutorials/examples).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the next person that runs into this, my problem was that my https local URLs (links and images) weren't using a valid certificate. Replacing them with http fixed the issue.

Comment: I can't test this because we no longer do anything with apple news but huge if true. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Typically this happens when the json is malformed or if incorrectly using an ANF property.

Comment: I'd rather not for work privacy reasons, but I will say that I downloaded the JSON from iCloud's apple news publisher after the article had successfully draft published. I also have been having the same result with the example articles downloaded from the Apple News documentation. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/apple_news/apple_news_format_tutorials/examples